# Pass a value to trigger click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got 3 buttons and I've used their calss to create a click function.

```
$('.abc').click(function(){
     if (val).is(':visible')){
       //do something
     }
});
```

I've got another click function as below

```
$(".custom-rmenu li").click(function(){
     // This is the triggered action name
     switch($(this).attr("data-action")) {
     // A case for each action.
       case "case1": alert("first"); break;
       case "case2": alert("second"); break;
       case "case3": alert("third"); break;
     }
});
```

My question is, I need to trigger the `$('.abc').` click function via the `$(".custom-rmenu li").` click function. How do I pass a value (val) from each case to the `$('.abc').` click function?

Comment: Here is demo please check it out. http://jsfiddle.net/0yu2zx3u/

Comment: How is your HTML built up? Is there a `.abc` button inside each `<li>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass parameters in `trigger` as follow:

```
$( ".abc").trigger( "click", [ "myParam1", "myParam2" ] );
```

And you can get the parameters:

```
$('.abc').click(function(e, myParam1, myParam2) {
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

`trigger` signature: `.trigger( eventType [, extraParameters ] )`

Comment: thanks. what's `"Custom"` and `"Event"` are referred to?

Comment: These are the params, you want to pass to the event handler

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery trigger function first parameter is the event to be triggered, you can pass any other data as second argument in array, like this:

```
.trigger('click', [val1, val2]);

.on('click', function(event, val1, val2) { ... })
```

Comment: @Becky These are example variables, to show you how to pass and access them. Just put your parameter you want to pass between `[]` and you can access it then in the event listener callback.

Comment: should there be 2 (val1 and val2)?

Comment: @Becky No you can pass whatever you want there. WHat you pass between `[]` will be accessible in the function callback.

Answer (score 0):

An incredible use of this could be like an "observer" from a class that you can't access because the click is been recognized by a vendor that produce a JS animation.

So, after executing the the animation in vendor you could call an listener inside in your main side effect class, triggering an observer.

First create and a DOM object to be a observer:

```
<a id='#observer'></a>
```

In your main class, declare the observer:

```
this.observer = $('#observer');
```

In the same class, define your function to handle listeners:

```
registerHandlers() {
    this.observer.off().click((e, params) => this[params.function](params.event));
}
```

In last, trigger the click inside the vendor, after animation:

```
$('vendor-class').on('click', function (event) {
    animationJs() // Vendor stuff...
    $('#observer').trigger( "click", [ {
      event,
      function:"myFunctionToHandleVendor",
    } ] );
}
```

**NOTE:.** The great achievement here is pass an object containing multiples variables, for this put the object inside an array.

```
[{type:'secret', user:'Jonh', msg:'Paul is dead!'}]
```